# Split <li> into two column

Tags: html, css, layout

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="ext-left">
            <img class="ext-icon" src="http://dummyimage.com/48x48/000/fff.png">
        </div>
        <div class="ext-right">
            <a class="ext-name" href="#">Extension Name</a>
            <p class="ext-intro">Introduction here</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I'd like to split the each list element into two part(in the same line), in the left is an image, in the right is a link and a text(they should be in two lines).
I tried to use float left on ext-left but it doen't work.
Play with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UeThn/1/
This is the correct version: http://jsfiddle.net/UeThn/10/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
.ext-left{

    float:left;
}
li{
    clear:both;
}
```

New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRzRx/)

Comment: Add a clear on the LI to reset the float on each one, i modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you do

```
<ul>
<li style="width:150px">
    <div style="width:100px;float:left">
        <img class="ext-icon" src="http://dummyimage.com/48x48/000/fff.png">
    </div>
    <div style="width:50px;float:right">
        <a class="ext-name" href="#">Extension Name</a>
        <p class="ext-intro">Introduction here</p>
    </div>
    <br clear="both"/>
</li>
```

The idea is as follows:
1. give the 'li' a width
2. give both div's a width
3. float left and right respectively
4. Add a beak with clear="both" at the end

Comment: Thats what you have to do to get it to work. And its not that much extra :P

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
li > div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeThn/20/)]

(But evil browsers won't support that, see info [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock))

Answer (score 0):

Floating left seemd to work. Think you've done something wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/UXnVJ/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give each div a set width - otherwise, they think they should be 100% wide, which doesn't allow the next to float next to it.  See [fiddle-fix here](http://jsfiddle.net/UeThn/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li {
    clear: left;
}

.ext-left {
    float: left;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Float both divs to the left

```
.ext-left, .ext-right{
    float: left;
}

li {
    clear: both;
}
```